# Ruby append to string if error contains string

Tags: ruby, slack, slack-api

I have a Slack Bot that needs to respond in an error condition.  If the error has certain text in it, I want to append some additional information to the return message. This block of code works fine if I comment out the `message +=` line but breaks if I do not.  When I try to replicate this in `irb` everything works fine too.

Does something look obviously wrong here?

```
begin
  scan = @nsc.scan_devices(devices)
rescue Nexpose::APIError => e
  puts "[!] API ERROR: Most likely caused by an orphaned asset (#{device_ids})"
  puts "[!] #{e}"
  $slackbot_logger.error("[!] API ERROR: Most likely caused by an orphaned asset (#{device_ids})")
  $slackbot_logger.error(e)

  # Message back to Slack
  message = "<@#{user_id}> scan for #{ip_list} *failed* :sob:"
  message += 'There is a scheduled blackout Tues/Thurs until 1000 CST' if e.include? 'blackout'

  SlackFunctions.slack_send_message(message, channel)
  return
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular error object (and maybe all error objects) did not have an `include?` method.  Therefore using `e.to_s` seems to do the trick.